# Starting the ipython notebook pager in a seperate tab or window

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I access the python help on a function or so with the ?, e.g. str? inside the IPython notebook, the help text appears below the notebook cells in a frame inside the same tab. Is it somehow possible to open the pager in a separate tab (or window) every time I look up a help topic in a cell?

It is possible to do it manually by clicking on the symbol in the right upper corner that says 'open the pager in an external window' but I would like to have this as the default behavior.